# Does the university from "Crimson Rivers" actually exist?

Tags: film-location, the-crimson-rivers

Does the university from "The Crimson Rivers" actually exist? The Wikipedia site mentions only "Guernon" in the French Alpes but a Google search did not help.

Is there an actual university in the French Alpes that you know about? I could not find anything that matches the search pattern of a relatively remote place in which the said incidents could have taken place.

Edit: The question is basically if there is any university in which said incidents could have taken place, i.e. an university that is remotely placed enough, in the Alpes for example OR if the university that the movie relates to actually exists (but has another name) or if the concept of an university in an Alpe valley is purely fiction. Of course I know that said incidents did not really take place (at least since Nazi Germany was defeated).

Comment: Seeing how the university was basically doing their very own breeding project over decades and using rather henious means to do so, I could imagine this movie to be a publicity nightmare if it really existed. ;-)

Comment: It couldn't possibly be right? regarding the facts that Napolean Wilson mentioned, and if it was, anyway being hidden and well guarded secret, we may never know.

Comment: You might have all misunderstood the question (in a strange way). I did not ask if there is an university that DOES all the things that the movie mentions (it would be a documentary then and no movie right), I just asked if there is an university that is relatively remotely located in the French Alpes or if the University of Guernon exists (but under another name since Google failed to find anything about it)

Comment: I know you didn't want to know if there was a university that *did* all this. But even if it didn't, using a real (and entirely innocent) university for the setting would still be bad publicity seeing what stuff the film accuses the university of *as a whole*. This is different from the university merely being used as a crime scene for some unrelated murder, the *entire* university is a perpetrator here.

Comment: Sure, therefore the (yet to be proofed) change of name. I am looking for a place that COULD have staged this kind of things...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about finding a non-movie related geographical location.

Comment: It isn't, it's about finding the movie's background reference. And IF you do vote so, don't tell and therefore block everyone's thinking process while they are reading through the contend. It's not helping even if the question was clearly off topic

Comment: While I don't agree with the close reason, it *is* helping to mention it as it first and foremost informs *you* about any potential problems with your question. Any other user who cannot close-vote can't make much of this comment anyway, and any user who *can* already sees the close-votes, too.

Comment: The location of the ficional university is described in the book the movie is based on: "...passing Saint-Martin d’Hères, Saint-Martin d’Uriage ... and located at the foot of Mt. Belledonne..."

Comment: cont.: ad-lib translation from http://www.leprogres.fr/sortir/2014/07/15/les-rivieres-pourpres-font-leur-lit-en-rhone-alpes). As there is no institute or campus nearby (the nearest one being in Grenoble), Guernon is a plain fictional place with no possible existing equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented before, the location of the ficitonal university is described in the book the movie is based on as '(starting from Grenoble)...passing Saint-Martin d’Hères, Saint-Martin d’Uriage ... and located at the foot of Mt. Belledonne...'(ad-lib translation from http://www.leprogres.fr/sortir/2014/07/15/les-rivieres-pourpres-font-leur-lit-en-rhone-alpes).

As there is no institute or campus nearby (the nearest one being in Grenoble, and also there's nothing much heading east except some ski ressorts), 'Guernon' is a plain fictional place with no possible existing equivalent.